# How to remove certain characters from Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, api, minecraft, bukkit

So i am trying to make a plugin for the Bukkit API for Minecraft and i am having this problem with Strings were i can not remove a certain part of the String, If you could help it would be much appreciated.

So the problem is occurs when i use the line of code: iter.next().toString();

That line of code prints out the input of: "ItemStack{DIAMOND_SWORD x 1}"

How would i remove the " x 1" part of the String and keep the rest after that if there is something?

Here is a list of things that i have tried:

- SubString
- Replace
- Split

Comment: How have you tried those things you tried?

Comment: what's wrong with replace()?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ probably has some info that will be helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace `[space(s)]x[space(s)][digit(s)]}` with just `}`. If that is the case then you can try using

```
replaceAll("\\s+x\\s+\\d+\\}", "}");
```

`replaceAll` uses [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) (regex) as first argument. In regex `\s` (written as `"\\s"`) represents any whitespace, `+` represents *one or more occurrences* of previously described element which means that `"\\s+"` represents one or more spaces. Now `\d` represents digit (character in range `0-9`). Also `{` and `}` are special characters so to escape them I needed to add `\\` before `}`.

---

UPDATE after you changed requirements:

```
replaceAll("ItemStack\\{(\\w+)\\s+x\\s+\\d+\\}", "{$1}");
```

`\\w` represents any character in range `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` and `_`. I surrounded `\\w+` with parenthesis to create [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) which will store `DIAMOND_SWORD` so I could use match from it in replacement part via `$[groupID]`. Since this is our first group its number is `1` so we could use `{$1}` in replacement to replace entire

```
ItemStack{DIAMOND_SWORD x 1}
```

with just `{DIAMOND_SWORD}`

Comment: Yes, this works but can you explain how the //s+x etc works its confusing.

Comment: Sorry to ask but i think i may need it to just output DIAMOND_SWORD.

Comment: In that case don't replace it with `{$1}` but only with `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this:

when you call iter.next() and you change the string which is returned, then you loose the reference on the string in your list.

this has to do with the behavior of strings: if you change a string you get in fact a reference to a new string object.

in combination with list usage you should try this i.e.:

```
iter.set(iter.next().substring(int i));
```

this takes care that the object you want gets placed into the list ...

Comment: I can't use anything that has to use constant numbers.

Comment: ? ... I wanted to show that your problem could lie in the wrong handling of the Iterator and the object reference. my statement is just an example (i.e.!). The exact code which solves your problem could be: iter.set(iter.next().substring(0, s.indexOf(" x 1")).concat("}"));

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove all but the first "word" inside the braces:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\{\\w+)[^}]+\\}","$1}");
```